# Releasing an Array crashes the app in xCode

Tags: arrays, xcode, crash, nsmutablearray, release

why does my app crash when releasing an array? Ive been trying to figure it out for HOURS! If I dont release it, it causes a memory leak. If I do release it, it crashes with this error:
    Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
Sometimes it also says this:
    Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)

Just cant work it out. Theres alot of code, so i will paste (what i think) is the relevant parts.

```
-(void)startGame:(int)levelNumber {

    //NOTE there is some code ive not pasted as its too big, but I dont think its relevant

levelsArray = [gameLevels loadLevelMap:levelNumber];
levelsArray_charGuards = [[levelsArray objectAtIndex:4]retain];


    //CREATE CHAR MAIN ########
charMainStore = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1] retain];

charMainToDestroy = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1] retain];

CharMain* charMain = [[CharMain alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((levels_charStart_x)*40), ((levels_charStart_y)*40), 0, 0)];
[viewController.mapView addSubview:charMain];

[self registerMainChar:charMain];
charMain.gameController = self;
charMain.currentGrid_x = levels_charStart_x;
charMain.currentGrid_y = levels_charStart_y;
charMain.nextGrid_x = levels_charStart_x;
charMain.nextGrid_y = levels_charStart_y;
mapViewController.gameController = self;

[self moveMap_x:((levels_charStart_x)*40) moveMap_y:((levels_charStart_y)*40)];

[charMain release];

 //CREATE CHAR GUARD ######## 
charGuardStore = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10] retain];
charGuardToDestroy = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10] retain]; 
    //These are both @synthesize properly
    //levelsArray_charGuards is from previously

    for (NSMutableArray* levelsArray_charGuards_path in levelsArray_charGuards) {

    NSMutableArray* levelsArray_charGuards_path_eachCoOrd = [levelsArray_charGuards_path objectAtIndex:0];

    int levels_charGuardStart_x = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[levelsArray_charGuards_path_eachCoOrd objectAtIndex:0]] intValue];
    int levels_charGuardStart_y = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[levelsArray_charGuards_path_eachCoOrd objectAtIndex:1]] intValue];

    CharGuard* charGuard = [[CharGuard alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((levels_charGuardStart_x*40), (levels_charGuardStart_y*40), 0, 0)];
    //CharGuard* charGuard = [[CharGuard alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((levels_charStart_x)*40), ((levels_charStart_y)*40), 0, 0)];

    [viewController.mapView addSubview:charGuard];

    [self registerGuardChar:charGuard];
    charGuard.gameController = self;
    [charGuard setImage];
    charGuard.currentGrid_x = levels_charGuardStart_x;
    charGuard.currentGrid_y = levels_charGuardStart_y;
    charGuard.nextGrid_x = levels_charGuardStart_x;
    charGuard.nextGrid_y = levels_charGuardStart_y;
    mapViewController.gameController = self;

    charGuard.levelsArray_charGuards_path = levelsArray_charGuards_path;

    [charGuard release];
    charGuard = nil;


    levelsArray_charGuards_path = nil;

    levelsArray_charGuards_path_eachCoOrd =nil;
}
}
```

When one level is finished, or is restarted, this is called:

```
-(void)clearLevel {
NSLog(@"Clear Level");

    for (CharMain* charMain in charMainStore){

    [charMain removeFromSuperview];
    [charMainToDestroy addObject:charMain];
}

for (CharMain* charMain in charMainToDestroy){

    [charMainStore removeObject:charMain];

}

for (CharGuard* charGuard in charGuardStore) {

    [charGuard removeFromSuperview];
    [charGuardToDestroy addObject:charGuard];

}

for (CharGuard* charGuard in charGuardToDestroy){

    [charGuardStore removeObject:charGuard];

}

    [charGuardStore release];
charGuardStore=nil;

[charMainStore release];
charMainStore=nil;

//[charGuardToDestroy release]; //If I allow this it crashes!***********
charGuardToDestroy= nil;

[charMainToDestroy release];
charMainToDestroy = nil;

}
```

The game then calls startGame:(int)levelNumber again.

I have other object which i havnt shown here but they all work fine. Its just the charGuardToDestroy that doesnt want to be released!

I have tried:

```
-(void)clearLevel {
NSLog(@"Clear Level");

    for (CharMain* charMain in charMainStore){

    [charMain removeFromSuperview];
    [charMainToDestroy addObject:charMain];
}

for (CharMain* charMain in charMainToDestroy){

    [charMainStore removeObject:charMain];

}

for (CharGuard* charGuard in charGuardStore) {

    [charGuard removeFromSuperview];
    //[charGuardToDestroy addObject:charGuard];

}
/*
for (CharGuard* charGuard in charGuardToDestroy){

    [charGuardStore removeObject:charGuard];

}
    */

    [charGuardStore release];
charGuardStore=nil;

[charMainStore release];
charMainStore=nil;

[charGuardToDestroy release]; //I tried allowing this and removing the above code ***********
charGuardToDestroy= nil;

[charMainToDestroy release];
charMainToDestroy = nil;

}
```

This also worked, but why?? I really need to be able to remove the charGuard from the screen, and from the array, then release it, but I can only do one or the other. Its strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you somewhere added a `CharGuard` object to the array charGuardStore which is only retained by this array and charGuards superview.

Here is what I think happens:

```
for (CharGuard* charGuard in charGuardStore) {

    [charGuard removeFromSuperview];             // charGuard only retained by charGuardStore (= 1 retain left)
    [charGuardToDestroy addObject:charGuard];    // charGuard retained by charGuardToDestroy too (= 2 retains left)

}

for (CharGuard* charGuard in charGuardToDestroy){

    [charGuardStore removeObject:charGuard];     // remove 1 retain (= 1 retain left) because it's still in charGuardToDestroy

}

/* more code */

[charGuardToDestroy release];                    // remove all charGuards. charGuard gets released. And most likely you access it later.
```

so most likely your bug happens already when you create the CharGuards. Probably overreleasing, but the effect shows up much much later.

Use [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled) to figure out if this is the case.

I think if you add `[charGuardToDestroy removeAllObjects];` after you have removed the charGuards from that array it will crash. This would confirm what I said.

Comment: Thanks. I used the Zombies (which I didnt know existed because it was greyed out) but this worked great and found some other bugs. Does [charGuard removeFromSuperview]; also release charGuard? I think part of the problem was within charGuard, under -(void)dealloc{} I was releasing charImage which was set earlier:
 NSString* tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"char_guard_%d_%d",2,1];
 
 UIImage* loadedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:tempStr];
 charImage = [loadedImage retain]; 
I thought this should have been released.

Comment: sorry for the late answer. Yes, removeFromSuperview will release the object 1 time. This release is just to counter the retain that was caused when you added that view with `addSubView:` to another view earlier. Looks like you retained charImage, so you have to release it in dealloc. Since you marked my answer as correct I hope you figured it out. Unfortunately sometimes memory bugs are hard to find.